# Can Garou, Mages, et al Resist the Ecstasy of a Vampire's Kiss?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

From the 20th Anniversary rules:

> Once the Kindred breaks her vessel’s skin with her fangs, that vessel
> no longer resists the vampire (if he did in the first place). Indeed,
> the ecstasy caused by the vampire’s bite is called the Kiss, and it
> engenders as much exquisite, subtly painful pleasure in vampires as it
> does in mortals. Exceptionally strong-willed mortals (9+ Willpower)
> may continue to resist, but even these vessels eventually succumb to
> the pleasure. Some Kindred and kine even develop lusts for the Kiss
> and actively seek out those who will drink their blood.
>
> Note: While
> Kindred find the Kiss pleasurable, they may resist it more readily
> than mortals can. Any Kindred, regardless of Willpower, may make a
> Self-Control/Instinct roll (difficulty 8) to avoid succumbing to the
> Kiss. This enables vampiric victims of diablerie (p. 293) to have a
> chance at fighting back.

Are there any notes, exceptions, or rules that would allow a Garou, Changing Breed, Mage, Ghoul, Mummy, or other supernatural creature to get a roll to resist the ecstasy of a vampire's kiss like the Kindred do?

Or is it just one of those things you would determine on a case by case basis with the Storyteller?

Comment: Note that many other templates cause very nasty side effects when drunk. The "taste" alone might be enough to get a feeding vampire to stop.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of any explicit rulings for other splats resisting the Kiss.  From what I recall of my time in the Old World of Darkness, there were a number of "holes" in the rules for interactions between different splats like this - especially for V:tM since it was the first and it really seemed like they hadn't planned on publishing any other supernatural creatures besides vampires (until they did.)

As far as how I would personally rule things:

- Any splat that's still living (garou, mage, etc) would get the same resistance roll a mortal does.  (Note that Ghouls are actually just normal people, blood-bound to a vampire, so they're definitely in this camp.)
- Kuei-Jin I'd give the same resistance roll as vampires, since they're a very similar type of supernatural creature.
- Other *undead splats* (mummies, embodied wraiths, etc) I'd probably have the *feeding vampire* make a roll to *continue* feeding, using similar difficulties.  it's also questionable what kind of sustenance the vampire would get from these beings anyway.
- Edit: As Wesley points out, mummies aren't technically undead in the Revised OWoD.  I'd still be inclined to lump them in this category for the purposes of my own house rules though.  It just "feels right." :)
- Constructs or other non-living creatures (Iteration X robots, golems) that may turn up and be mistaken for food, I would rule the Kiss doesn't even kick in for them.  IIRC, the feeding vampire also feels some sensation during The Kiss, so they will likely realize their mistake very quickly.

Comment: Revised mummies aren't undead. In fact, they're very much living. They just regenerate even past death.

Comment: My bad, it has been a while.  Although I seem to recall something about mummies being repulsive to eat (even animals won't touch them) so it still feels thematically correct to treat them this way.  It's a house rule anyway, YMMV ;)

Comment: Mummy: the Resurrection mummies are so alive, they feed a vampire for double the blood, can't be turned to vampires and (as the book suggests) are prone to be mad at the leech that stole their blood.